# Tax-query on taxonomy doesn´t work

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I am trying to get out a custom posttypes that belongs to a specific taxonomy.
I don't get it sorted out on taxonomy, it takes every custom post. I use this code

```
    global $post;
$terms = get_terms('resmal');
foreach ($terms as $term) :
    echo get_term_link($term);
    //Define the query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'resor',
        'tax-query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'resmal',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'Italien'
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // Start the Loop
    if( $query->have_posts() ):
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
            $query->the_post();
            echo get_the_title();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;
```

The custom posttype

```
function base_register_resor_post_type() {
  $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Våra Resor'),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Resa' ),
        'add_new' => __('Skapa ny'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Skapa ny Resa'),
        'edit_item' => __('Redigera Resa'),
        'new_item' => __('Ny Resa'),
        'view_item' => __('Visa Resa'),
        'search_items' => __('Sök Resa'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Hittade inget'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Papperskorgen är tom!')
  );
  $args = array(
        'labels'                            => $labels,
        'public'                            => true,
        'has_archive'               => 'resor',
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'                       => true,
        'query_var'                     => true,
        'rewrite'                       => array('slug' => 'resa'),
        'taxonomies' => array('resmal'),
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'supports'                      => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','revisions'),
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'hierarchical'              => true
  );
  register_post_type('resor', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'base_register_resor_post_type');
```

The taxonomy

```
function base_register_destination_taxonomy() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => 'Resmål',
    'singular_name'     => 'Resmål',
    'search_items'      => 'Sök Resmål',
    'all_items'         => 'Alla Resmål',
    'parent_item'       => 'Parent Location',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Location:',
    'edit_item'         => 'Ändra Resmål',
    'update_item'       => 'Updatera Resmål',
    'add_new_item'      => 'Lägg till nytt Resmål',
    'new_item_name'     => 'Nytt Resmål namn',
    'menu_name'         => 'Resmål'
  );

  $args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels'       => $labels,
    'has_archive'  => true,
    'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'resmal' ),
    'public'       => true
  );
  register_taxonomy('resmal', array('resor'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'base_register_destination_taxonomy');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in the first snippet that is

```
'tax-query' => array(
```

instead of

```
'tax_query' => array(
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfect